# Как нарисовать только часть картинки в OpenGl

Tags: изображения, текстура, opengl

Здравствуйте! Осваиваю OpenGl. Вот так я рисую целую текстуру:

```
void drawImage2d(GLuint texture, float srcx, float srcy, float srcw, float srch, float x, float y, float w, float h){
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(srcw, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(w, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(srcw, srch);
glVertex3f(w, h, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, srch);
glVertex3f(0.0f, h, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
}
```

А как мне нарисовать только часть текстуры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В TexCoord2f передаются координаты фрагмента, который нужно нарисовать. У Вас srcx и srcy не задействованы.